# Is there advantage of using (void *) 1 instead of null for placeholder

Tags: c

I was wondering if there is any difference/advantage of using `(void *) 1` instead of `null` when assigning "empty" values. (in C)

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have a need to differentiate `NULL` pointers from your `(void *) 1`, you should use `NULL` to represent empty pointers for a number of reasons.

1. Calling `free` on a `NULL` pointer will not crash your program. It will instead just do nothing.
2. It will be much easier for other people to understand your code.
3. Many library functions accept NULL as a valid value for "empty" parameters. No library functions accept `(void *) 1` as a valid value.

Comment: @user3386109, Please feel free to edit this answer and add to it. :)

Comment: @user3386109, You have 2k+ rep, you have edit privileges on all questions and answers. :)

Comment: I again added my bit to supplement your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the reasons stated by @merlin, I would like to add that the C99 standard §6.3.2.3 ¶3 says

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is **guaranteed to compare unequal to
>   a pointer to any object or function**.

Therefore, the standard guarantees that the null pointed defined by the macro `NULL` (in the header `stddef.h`) or the expression `0` cannot compare to the address of any object in memory. Using `(void *) 1` can therefore cause problems if, by chance, it compares equal to the address of an object. It's not advisable to do it and should be avoided.